# sql many to many select with join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a select statement and I just cant get it work.

I have 3 tables:
`places`, `tags`, `places_tags`

```
Places:
   - id
   - name

Tags:
   - id
   - name

Places_tags:
   - place_id
   - tag_id
   - order
```

I am trying to select places and join the first tag that inserted (using order)

```
        SELECT p.*, t.tag_id AS tag
        FROM `places` as p
        LEFT JOIN places_tags t ON (t.place_id = p.id)
        group by p.id
```

That's what I have right now.
I need to add somthing like ORDER BY order DESC...

I think that I'm not doing it right.

Comment: Please consider improving your accepetance rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
SELECT 
   p.name AS "place", 
   t.name AS "firstTag" 
FROM 
   places p 
   LEFT JOIN
   places_tags pt1 
      ON pt1.place_id = p.id
   LEFT JOIN
   places_tags pt2 
      ON pt2.place_id = p.id AND pt2.tag_id < pt1.tag_id
   LEFT JOIN 
   tags t 
      ON t.id = pt1.tag_id
WHERE
   pt2.tag_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Cant see how that answer helps me

Comment: @Amir The basic idea is to use a self `LEFT JOIN` and filter on records where the id column is the smallest in the result.

Comment: @Amir I updated my solution to apply the approach. Sorry if it wasn't clear :)